# Is there a smallest $r$ such that $n+\varphi(n)=\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^r q_i$ always has solutions for mutually different odd primes $q_i $?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-functions

While discussing with Peter in one of the chatrooms on MSE I proposed an idea to try to find smallest natural number $r$ such that $n+\varphi(n)=\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^r q_i$ has solutions for every choice of mutually different $r$ odd primes $q_i:i=1,...,r$.

Of course, I do not know is there really such an $r$, therefore this question.

Because $n+ \varphi(n)$ is "relatively dense" in $\mathbb N$ it seems that there *could* be such a smallest $r$ since as $r$ becomes larger and larger the product $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^rq_i$ becomes "nicely" dense (but how much and how much nicely) in $\mathbb N$, so it seems, at least from a naive standpoint, that some $r$ could strike a sensible balance between the two requirements.

But then, "on the other hand", the requirement that there is a solution *for every* choice of $r$ mutually different odd primes seems as to really be "too much" to be fulfilled.

Peter computed the smallest numbers for which there is no $n$ that is a solution for $r=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ and these are:

$7, 35, 195, 1155, 15015, 255255, 4849845, 140645505$

This sequence is not in OEIS.

Furthermore,  if $2$ is allowed to be one of the primes, which we do not consider in this question, then the corresponding sequence is also not in OEIS.

The question:

- Is there a smallest natural number $r$ such that $n+\varphi(n)=\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^r q_i$ has solutions for every choice of mutually different $r$ odd primes $q_i:i=1,...,r$?

I can admit I didn´t think too much about this problem, but straightforwardly typed it here because I know that some folks here know about these topics more than I, so I can expect an answer and(or) a comment which settles the "whole thing".

Now, when I again think of this, for small $r$ this product is rather "wildly" distributed over $\mathbb N$, but also is for large $r$.

So some density arguments seem to be surely needed, it would be next to a wonder if $n + \varphi(n)$ could really "cover" all the products for some $r$, in whose existence I seriously doubt.

Comment: Of course "is there a smallest natural number $r$ such that …" is the same as "is there an $r$ such that …", by well ordering; what's the advantage of wording it this way?  Beyond that, I think that MO is not the place for questions containing "I didn't think too much about this problem."

Comment: @LSpice Of course, when you think that MO is not the place for questions like this one, you vote to close, as you did?

Comment: I think there doesn't exist such $r$ , such that any $r$ distinct $q_i$ would satisfy the relation. There must exist some choice of $q_i$s for all $r$ such that for some $q_i \in \Lambda$ a subset of {$q_i$}, always won't be possible $2q_i-1=q_jq_lq_k$ . We can choose a very diverse set of $q_i$ for each $r$.

Comment: For example we choose $q_1<q_2<q_3....$ such a way that neither $q_j≠2q_i-1, i<j$ nor $q_i|2q_j-1 ,j>i$ strongly all $q_j≠2q_i-1$ and all $2q_i-1$ are prime. For example, $3,7,19, 31, 37, 43,....$.

Comment: I've had great difficulty parsing this question in such a way that it makes sense. I think you're hoping to find (or prove the existence of) an integer $r$ such that every product of $r$ distinct primes can be written in the form $n+\phi(n)$ for some $n$, but for eack $k<r$ there is a product of $k$ distinct primes that can't be written that way.

Comment: "This sequence is not in OEIS." True, but the last five terms are. See https://oeis.org/A048599 and https://oeis.org/A074043

Answer (score -2):

This is just an idea may it help you. I think your problem related to the primorial numbers. In particular rate growth of $\frac{\phi(n)}{n}$, Nicolas showed that there are infinitely many numbers, primorials, such that:
$$  \frac{n}{e^\gamma \log \log n + \frac{2.50637}{\log \log n}} < \varphi(n) < \frac{n}{e^\gamma \log \log n  }.$$ You may check [here](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/publications.html) the paper of Nicolas, in French. Then, we assume the existence of infinity of premorial numbers. This means that:$$  \frac{1}{e^\gamma \log \log n + \frac{2.50637}{\log \log n}} <\frac{ \varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{1}{e^\gamma \log \log n  }.$$ Now you can replace $\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}$  by $\displaystyle \frac{\prod_{i=1}^r q_i}{n}-1 $ we get:
$$  \frac{1}{e^\gamma \log \log n + \frac{2.50637}{\log \log n}} <\frac{\prod_{i=1}^r q_i}{n}-1 < \frac{1}{e^\gamma \log \log n  }.$$
Really I suspect there is such an $r$ using the latter identity but really I don't know the way to get it only we may look to when does that product in the last identity close to $1$ because squeeze theorem would be hold in this case.

**ADDENDUM** Also another question  we may ask here is what is the smallest $r$ for which $n\mid(\prod_{i=1}^r q_i)$ in the last identity? But this seems so hard.

Comment: Why do you use `{ ,}` (space(s) and a comma) rather than a period?  I found it very hard to read, so I edited to the more usual punctuation, but of course you can roll back if you disagree.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Sorry, but this answer doesn't make any sense.  What does the existence of small values of $\phi(n)/n$ have to do with the problem?